# loopback update default method (authorization required)

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

i created a model witch have user default class as base class,
so i didn't succeed to launch update even when i set acl as shown:

```
{
"accessType": "*",
"principalType": "ROLE",
"principalId": "$everyone",
"permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

> "error": {
>       "statusCode": 401,
>       "name": "Error",
>       "message": "Authorization Required",
>       "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
>       ...

Answer (score 0):

User is a built-in model in Loopback, so it might be that there is already a more specific rule declared on this model. Check [this article](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html#acl-rule-precedence) to see how ACL rules work in Loopback.